# jqGrid: Added one extra group for grouping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I want to add grouping to my jqGrid. I have a simple model:

```
public class ViolationViewModel
{       
    [JqGridColumnFormatter(JqGridColumnPredefinedFormatters.Date, SourceFormat = "d.m.Y H:i:s", OutputFormat = "d.m.Y H:i")]
    public DateTime FixationTime { get; set; }       
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string ViolationType { get; set; }
}
```

This is code in a view:

```
@{
      var grid = new JqGridHelper<ViolationViewModel>("myGrid",
      dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
      methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
      pager: true,
      sortingName: "ViolationType",
      sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
      url: Url.Action("Violation", "Cabinet"),
      viewRecords: true,
      rowsList: new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 50, 100 },
      loadOnce: true,
      multiSelect: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      groupingEnabled: true,
      groupingView: new JqGridGroupingView { ColumnShow = new[] { false }, Fields = new[] { "ViolationType" }, DataSorted = true},         
    ).FilterToolbar(new JqGridFilterToolbarOptions() { StringResult = true })
    .Navigator(new JqGridNavigatorOptions() { Add = false, Delete = false, Edit = false, View = false, Refresh = false, Search = false });

}
```

I have 16 records, 15 records with the same `ViolationType`, 1 record have other value .

The problem with that jqGrid create three (must be two) groups, but there are two groups have the same caption. But when I click on any column (change sort) then all works fine and I have two groups.

Where is a problem?

One more question: in the `rowList` option I have the first value as `10`. But when my grid is loaded default value is `20`. How to setup it to first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `DataSorted` to `true`. In this case the data from the initial request should be already properly sorted (by 'ViolationType') on the server side and returned in proper order.

For the second part of your question, just set `rowsNumber` to `10` for intial value:

```
@{
    var grid = new JqGridHelper<ViolationViewModel>("myGrid",
        dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
        methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
        pager: true,
        sortingName: "ViolationType",
        sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
        url: Url.Action("Violation", "Cabinet"),
        viewRecords: true,
        rowsList: new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 50, 100 },
        rowsNumber: 10,
        loadOnce: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        groupingEnabled: true,
        groupingView: new JqGridGroupingView { ColumnShow = new[] { false }, Fields = new[] { "ViolationType" }, DataSorted = true},         
    )
    .FilterToolbar(new JqGridFilterToolbarOptions() { StringResult = true })
    .Navigator(new JqGridNavigatorOptions() { Add = false, Delete = false, Edit = false, View = false, Refresh = false, Search = false });
}
```